# How do I block a website on my iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, parental-controls

Like how you put `127.0.0.1 example.com` in the `hosts` file on a real computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [block a website on iOS 7 or later](http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-block-websites-on-safari-for-iphone-and-ipad-in-ios-7/), go to `Settings > General > Restrictions > Enable Restrictions` then `Restrictions > Websites > Limit Adult Content` then `Restrictions > Websites > Never Allow > Add a Website` and add the website you wish to block.

Comment: This doesn't just block the one site it blocks all kinds of sites including stackexchange

Comment: @gman If there's a website that gets blocked that you don't want to get blocked, just add it to the `Always Allow` list.

Comment: I don't want to have to add 1000s of sites. When I enabled that option pretty much every site I tried to go to failed. Sites that had nothing to do with adult content. Sites that were google results to normal places, restuarnts, stores, events, etc...

Comment: That sounds like Apple went overboard with the restrictions. I now see people with similar issues dating back to as early as 2014. Do you think you could post a question here describing it? There are a few people here that would see it and probably know what the issue is or know a workaround.